# spring integration amqp channel error handler auto ack

Tags: java, error-handling, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I have an amqp-backed channel `<int-amqp:channel>` to temporarily persist messages coming from a JDBC inbound adapter.  when no exception is thrown, the message is ack'd and removed from the rabbit queue.  when an exception occurs, the message is returned to the queue and is reprocessed continuosly.  There are some circumstances where I'd like the request to go back to the queue, but in most cases I just want to log the error and acknowledge the request (remove from the rabbit queue).

I've implemented an errorHandler to deal with thrown exceptions and allow for logging and "successful" completion, however even after handling, the original request is redelivered to the rabbit queue (unacknowledged)

in the inbound-rabbit-adapter, there is a property for error-channel and handling the message on the errorChannel allows me to achieve the desired behavior described above.  the only error property on the amqp channel is errorhandler.

any suggestions on a configuration that would allow me to meet my requirements?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`. See [3.9 Exception Handling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#exception-handling).

The [default error handler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java) does that for message conversion exceptions (which are likely irrecoverable).

In fact you can use that error handler by injecting a custom `FatalExceptionStrategy`.